# navigator.mediaDevices not available on iOS 14.3

Tags: ios, wkwebview, getusermedia

In the past, `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` was not available on WKWebView, but it has now been added as part of iOS 14.3, as these links show:

1. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/88052?answerId=668022022#668022022 (original thread)
2. https://caniuse.com/stream (see note 3)
3. https://webkit.org/blog/11353/mediarecorder-api

However, I updated the deployment target of an application to iOS 14.3 and then attached the Safari debugger to the WKWebView, but `navigator.mediaDevices` still returns undefined when run on the JS console. In the third link above there are suggestions on steps to take in order to use `getUserMedia`.

> `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` can now be exposed to WKWebView applications. `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` is automatically exposed if the embedding application is able to natively capture either audio or video. Please refer to Apple documentation to meet these requirements.

I have followed the steps just in case but I still face the same problem.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? Has anyone else faced the same problem?

Comment: Tested on iOS 14.5 and I see `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` defined as: `function getUserMedia() { [native code] } = $1` . Don't have 14.3 to test with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is your content is not secure. If you navigate to a https:// location, navigator.mediaDevices will be available.

See 2nd note on this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia

Comment: Thank you. This was the underlying cause, although in my case I was accessing `navigator.userAgent` before the page (which is https, by the way) got loaded onto the webview. As a result, `navigator` seemed to assume that it was an unsecure origin and disabled media capture, even after the page finished loading. Simply removing the user agent code did the trick.

Comment: @VictorDurojaiye what do you mean with "Simply removing user agent code" ?

Answer (score 0):

In Info.plist add:
`Privacy - Camera Usage Description`
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/requesting_authorization_for_media_capture_on_ios

And in order video element could play from your camera:

```
let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
```

How to play: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia